# capture anything but string

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have the following 7 strings

```
Seven Swans a Swimming
Six Geese a Laying
Five Golden Rings
Four Calling Birds
Three French Hens
Two Turtle Doves
and a Partridge in a Pear Tree
```

I want to write a regex to capture only the last 5 strings **by using negation, negating "Geese" and "Swans"**. Is there a straightforward way to do it?
My best solution is https://regex101.com/r/QprpQZ/1.

The equivalent solution I would like to get is:

```
.*(Golden|Birds|Hens|Doves|Partridge in a Pear Tree).*
```

Comment: this one https://regex101.com/r/QprpQZ/2 ?

Comment: Rephrasing: you want to capture any line that does *not* contain certain words (certain substrings)?

Comment: yeah does not contain certain substrings, and that means using `\b` word boundaries are also useful